# How to "hide" text in center of d3 zoomable sunburst when zooming?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I have added text and (a graphic) to the center of my sunburst and I'd like it be hidden when zoomed.

```
            svg.append("image")
                    .attr("xlink:href", "scholarWorksDark.png")
                    .attr("x", -80)
                    .attr("y", -150)
                    .attr("width", "150")
                    .attr("height", "150"); 
                    //.on("click", click(d));


        svg.append("text")
            //.on("click",click)
            .attr("x", -115)
            .attr("y", 90)
            .style("font-size",16)
            //.style("font-weight","bold")
            .html("Click to explore our <br/><br/>" +  hierarchy.value + " ETDs");
```

As you can see in my [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/AiktsrivUl7neNGjBnGt)

When I click on a section of the sunburst the text remains visible, I only want it to show when it's in the "home" state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered on the d3 Google Group:
Needed to add a class to the text in the center:

```
svg.append("text")
            //.on("click",click)
            .attr("class","center-text")
            .attr("x", -115)
        .attr("y", 90)
            .style("font-size",16)
            //.style("font-weight","bold")
            .html("Click to explore our <br/><br/>" +  hierarchy.value + " ETDs");

        function click(d) {
            path.transition()
                .duration(750)
                .attrTween("d", arcTween(d));
            if(d.key !== "ETD"){
              svg.select(".center-text")
                 .style("display","none")
            } else {
              svg.select(".center-text")
                 .style("display","")
            }
            mouseout();
        };
```